# Formula that refers to a sheet that does not yet exist

Tags: google-sheets

I have a workbook with different sheets for each day of the month. I create the sheets as the days go by. Each sheet refers to the next day (the after sheet that does not yet exist). After the following sheet is created, the formula does not update and leaves the old result. And yet when we select the formula, the good result is visible in the comments:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oghA.jpg)

How do we get the formula to update?

Thank you

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Force the function to update when the new sheet is created                                                  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XFg45kSdMNoKRaaxvBsXzXbOYKuHdgbNjuGA09f88MU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set this to every minute

[image]

and use this formula:

```
=IF(NOW()>NOW()-1; 
 IF($A$1="Date";;IFERROR(INDIRECT(DAY(A1+1)&"/"&TEXT(MONTH(A1);"00")&"/"&YEAR(A1)&"!L18"); 
 "faux")))
```

it won't be instant but it will take just a minute :)